# Paperclip gem is crashing the user's session in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have found similar questions to that, but mine is a little bit different.
(Paperclip 3.4.1, Rails 3.2.12, Ruby 1.9.3p392, using Pow 0.40)

Here is my model:

```
class Smoke < ActiveRecord::Base

  [...]

  attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude, :description, :picture

  validates_length_of :description, :minimum => 2, :maximum => 256, :allow_blank => true
  validates_presence_of :latitude, :longitude

  scope :with_picture, where("picture_file_name IS NOT NULL")

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :smoke_reports, :dependent => :destroy

  has_attached_file :picture,
    :default_url => "/assets/missing/:style.jpg",
    :styles => { :thumb => ["55x55", :jpg], :medium => ["500x500", :jpg], :original => ["800x800", :jpg] },
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => 'my-bucket-dev',
    :path => "/:class/:style/:id.:extension",
    :url => ":s3_domain_url",
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => 'mys3credentials',
      :secret_access_key => 'mys3credentials'
  }

  validates_attachment_size :picture,
    :less_than => 2.megabytes

  validates_attachment_content_type :picture,
    :content_type => /^image\/(jpg|jpeg|pjpeg|png|x-png)$/,
    :message => "Invalid image type. Only jpg/jpeg or png will be accepted."

  [...]

end
```

*Where '[...]' I omitted unrelated stuffs.*

When validates_attachment_size or validates_attachment_content_type gives a fail, some error occur and all my session data is cleaned (even my login).

That's all what appears in the application logs, check it:

```
Started POST "/smokes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-14 23:48:38 -0300
Processing by SmokesController#create as HTML
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Redirected to http://weedmap.dev/login
Filter chain halted as :deny_unlogged_users rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

And the follow is what the log shows when my uploaded file pass trough these two validation methods. So this error only appears when the file does not validate. Check:

```
Started POST "/smokes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-14 23:33:33 -0300
Processing by SmokesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DU+9CCVAzIxBbeccCWR1z4IzfQHxpiht6xPVCS/q3tc=", "latitude"=>"58.81374171570781", "longitude"=>"77.87109375", "picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9f9c17e330 @original_filename="Untitled-1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"Untitled-1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/6n/2zzqcbfd1c51xz1phh8sz17h0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130514-59252-1xbz3zf>>, "description"=>"", "commit"=>"Create"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/6n/2zzqcbfd1c51xz1phh8sz17h0000gn/T/Untitled-120130514-59252-bu86an.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/6n/2zzqcbfd1c51xz1phh8sz17h0000gn/T/Untitled-120130514-59252-bu86an.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "800x800" '/var/folders/6n/2zzqcbfd1c51xz1phh8sz17h0000gn/T/Untitled-120130514-59252-bu86an20130514-59252-l87c43.jpg'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/6n/2zzqcbfd1c51xz1phh8sz17h0000gn/T/Untitled-120130514-59252-bu86an20130514-59252-l87c4320130514-59252-km9don.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/6n/2zzqcbfd1c51xz1phh8sz17h0000gn/T/Untitled-120130514-59252-bu86an20130514-59252-l87c4320130514-59252-km9don.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "55x55" '/var/folders/6n/2zzqcbfd1c51xz1phh8sz17h0000gn/T/Untitled-120130514-59252-bu86an20130514-59252-l87c4320130514-59252-km9don20130514-59252-4r2p3r.jpg'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/6n/2zzqcbfd1c51xz1phh8sz17h0000gn/T/Untitled-120130514-59252-bu86an20130514-59252-l87c4320130514-59252-km9don.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/6n/2zzqcbfd1c51xz1phh8sz17h0000gn/T/Untitled-120130514-59252-bu86an20130514-59252-l87c4320130514-59252-km9don.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "500x500" '/var/folders/6n/2zzqcbfd1c51xz1phh8sz17h0000gn/T/Untitled-120130514-59252-bu86an20130514-59252-l87c4320130514-59252-km9don20130514-59252-1byzja6.jpg'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "smokes" ("created_at", "description", "latitude", "longitude", "picture_content_type", "picture_file_name", "picture_file_size", "picture_updated_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Wed, 15 May 2013 02:33:33 UTC +00:00], ["description", ""], ["latitude", 58.81374171570781], ["longitude", 77.87109375], ["picture_content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["picture_file_name", "Untitled-1.jpg"], ["picture_file_size", 8623], ["picture_updated_at", Wed, 15 May 2013 02:33:33 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Wed, 15 May 2013 02:33:33 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", nil]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "versions" ("created_at", "event", "ip", "item_id", "item_type", "object", "whodunnit") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Wed, 15 May 2013 02:33:33 UTC +00:00], ["event", "create"], ["ip", "127.0.0.1"], ["item_id", 17], ["item_type", "Smoke"], ["object", nil], ["whodunnit", #<User id: 1, name: "Fernando Schuindt", email: "f.schuindtcs@gmail.com", password_digest: nil, created_at: "2013-05-07 23:23:42", updated_at: "2013-05-10 06:18:41", external_provider: true, avatar_setup: 3>]]
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving /smokes/original/17.jpg
[AWS S3 200 2.147466 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"weedsquare-dev",:content_length=>8623,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::FileAdapter: Untitled-120130514-59252-bu86an20130514-59252-l87c43.jpg,:key=>"smokes/original/17.jpg")
```

I am pretty lost.
Any help?

**UPDATE:**

Here is part of my SmokesController:

```
class SmokesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :deny_unlogged_users, :except => [:new, :show, :count, :refresh_profile]
  before_filter :only_ajax, :only => [:new, :count, :refresh_profile]
  before_filter :only_with_smoke_params, :only => [:create]

  [...]

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @smoke = Smoke.new
    @smoke.latitude = params[:latitude]
    @smoke.longitude = params[:longitude]
    @smoke.picture = params[:picture]
    @smoke.description = params[:description]
    if @smoke.save
      @user.smokes << @smoke
      redirect_to @smoke
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  [...]

end
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Talking about this on the #rubyonrails@freenode.net everyone asked me about my form.
Then I realized that I was setting authenticity_token manually as you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5582495). Now the form_tag is doing it automatically. (The Rails do it by default but I don't knew)

Anyway, here is my form, and still the same error, same thing:

```
  <div id="new-smoke-form">
    <%= form_tag '/smokes', :multipart => true, :method => "post" do %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'latitude', @smoke.latitude %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'longitude', @smoke.longitude %>
      <div id="new-smoke-picture">
        <p>Upload a picture (optional):</p>
        <%= file_field_tag 'picture' %>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="new-smoke-description">
        <p>Talk about it:</p>
        <div id="new-smoke-remain" class="new-smoke-remain">256</div>
        <%= text_area_tag 'description', nil, :class => "new-smoke-textarea", :id => "new-smoke-textarea" %>
      </div>
      <%= submit_tag "Create", :class => "new-smoke-button" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

I am getting mad.

Comment: Can you post your form also please? I think your problems comes from the csrf token like the WARNING in the log says. If you are not authorized through the token, the session will be cleared. So please check your csrf stuff..

Comment: Well, I think that everything is ok with the form. Because when I use good images in the upload (images that will pass in the paperclip validators) no problem happen. But sure, here is it: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5582495

Comment: This problem makes me to use Carrierwave instead of Paperclip, it's pretty cool.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this issue today, it looks like it's an issue with Pow rather than Paperclip, related to this: https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/125

I've only managed to get it working by using Pow as a port proxy to WEBrick instead of as a Rack app, hopefully that helps you too.